# How to join 2 tables with some of transpose row to columns

Tags: sql

for example i have 2 tables

**info_table**

`id  |    Title     |   description
1   |     title1    |     dec1
2   |    title2     |     dec2
3   |     title3    |     dec3`

**Instance_Table**

`e_id  |    name     |     string
1      |     date    |     2015/01/19
2      |    time     |     10:00
3      |     value   |     10 
1      |     date    |     2015/01/20
2      |    time     |     11:00
3      |     value   |     12 
1      |     date    |     2015/01/21
2      |    time     |     12:00
3      |     value   |     13`

What result expected:

`id  |    Title     |     date      |   Time    |     value    |     Description
1   |    title1     |   2015/01/19 |   10:00    |     10       |     Des1
2   |    title2     |   2015/01/20 |   11:00    |     11       |     Des2
3   |    title3     |   2015/01/21 |   12:00    |     13       |     Des3`

Comment: Use pivot  for second table and join them

Comment: you `instance_table` is kinda vague to me.. i couldn't understand the second column.. and your expected result, the id 2 must have a title2, also  the id 3

Comment: You second table should have same eid for which you want to select in same row.

Comment: You need [coalesce](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68089/how-to-use-coalesce-with-multiple-rows-and-without-preceding-comma) to do this. only coalesce will not help you but, u can use this feature to get the result like that. you need to implement loop and temp table too.

Comment: As per @SridharDD comment, You will need a foreign key to join info_table and instance_table in instance_table, to pivot is secondary opinion.

Comment: Never store data like you do in Instance_Table, it will only cause you problems - as you may have noticed now... Use different columns (or tables) for different type of values.

Comment: Do you have fk in instance to info table? Where is the field to join by?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f88b2/1 this data makes some sense

Comment: How do you know that `Title1` and `10` go together on the same output row?  There's nothing to connect them together, so it just seems arbitrary or random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should integrate a Foreign Key on the Instance_Table, and your e_id should be a Primary Key.

**info_table**

```
id | Title | description 
1 | title1 | dec1 
2 | title2 | dec2 
3 | title3 | dec3
```

**Instance_Table**

```
e_id | name | string | FK_InfoTable
1 | date | 2015/01/19 | 1
2 | time | 10:00 | 1
3 | value | 10 | 1
4 | date | 2015/01/20 | 2
5 | time | 11:00 | 2
6 | value | 12 | 2
7 | date | 2015/01/21 | 3
8 | time | 12:00 | 3
9 | value | 13 |3
```

And with that kind of SQL Statement you should get what you want.

```
SELECT * FROM info_table INNER JOIN Instance_Table ON info_table.id = Instance_Table.FK_InfoTable
```

You can read on relationnal database here
[Relationnal database WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database)